# C# SerialPort class receives incorrect data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I currently have a program made using VB6 code that uses the MSCOMM control to pull back data from the serial port. This manages to successfully receive the data from my serial port, in which a Denso BHT-904B device is connected.

I am now trying to move this code over to C# so it fits in with a new piece of software that i am developing. To do this i am using the SerialPort class. However, the issue is that when i open the port up the data received event only fires when the device fails to communicate (which im guessing is due to a timeout). The data then received in the event is '↑↑↑↑↑'.

My SerialPort control settings are the following:

- DtrEnable = True
- PortName = COM3
- ReadBufferSize = 1024
- WriteBufferSize = 512

The code that i am using behind my form control is:

```
namespace BHTTestingDotNet
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string rxString;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.Default;

        serialPort.DataReceived += serialPort_DataReceived;
        serialPort.ErrorReceived += serialPort_ErrorReceived;
        serialPort.Open();

    }

    private void serialPort_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }

    private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        var test = serialPort.BytesToRead;
        SerialPort sr = (SerialPort)sender;
        rxString = sr.ReadExisting();
        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(displayText));
    }

    private void displayText(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBHT.AppendText(rxString);
    }
}
}
```

I have already tried to set both `RtsEnable` and `DtrEnable` to `true` but that didn't make any difference.

UPDATE - I have now changed to protocol settings on the device but i now only receive pipes and then a return symbol, for example like so:
|||||¬

Comment: You ought to call BeginInvoke , and don't assign the event on each buttonclick. But there are too much details (settings) we can't see here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman

Thanks for your help. I am currently only clicking this button once as it is just a little test application i have made to get this working before i move the code to my other application. Are there any other settings i can provide you with to help solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Create the Port in code and only set the properties you're sure of. Experiment with 1 at a time.

Comment: And also handle the ErrorReceived event.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok so i have now created my port object in code & i have also added an event handler in for the Error Received event. When the device fails to communicate it goes into the data received event and i receive the 5 arrows (as mentioned in my original post). However, it never goes into the error received event. Can you think of anything else i can try? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm out of ideas but do update your question with the new code. Saves some guesswork.

Comment: @HenkHolterman All up to date :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok, so i have the VB6 program on the same machine, this uses the MSCOMM control and it works fine. The settings all appear the same, but what is weird is that the VB6 code doesn't use a datareceived event but instead the OnComm event. This seems to fire instantly as soon as i start to send a batch on the device. When using the SerialPort class in .NET i send the batch on the device but it times out after approximately 15 seconds and then fires the datareceived event.

In terms of the terminal program, do you mean just move the code to a console application?

Thanks!

Comment: Just checking the obvious stuff... You have got the baud rate, parity, stop bits settings right? If they are wrong you often see corrupted but consistent data come back from the port. 
Also its probably worth doing some testing with a simple serial port console (I've used RealTerm in the past, its a bit quirky but free), their are also serial port sniffers that will show you exactly whats going on, so you can see the difference between whats working and you new code (not come across a free sniffer though).

Comment: Also your codes not thread safe (probably not the issue), but serialPort_DataReceived could be called several times before the first invoke call to displayText is called, causing you to miss data.
While testing just write what you read to the console or debug output, in production code I would recommend you pass the string to displayText, not use a member variable.

Comment: Do you have the relevant snippets of VB code to post, if you may? Sometimes it helps looking at the two pieces of code in parallel.

Comment: as the EventHandler is asychronous you cannot guarantee the state of rxString by the time it executes the code txtBHT.AppendText(rxString);   Another data receive event could have happened and displaced the data you are putting into rxString.   Since you are using the data string as the sender for the EventHandler you should be doing txtBHT.AppendText((string)o);

Comment: Also why do serial port twice --- var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;  and SerialPort sr = (SerialPort)sender;

Answer (score -2):

I am using SerialPort class  often and for my purposes I have made my own class

**public class SerialPortDataSource : SerialPort**

where SerialPort.DataReceived handler invoke this method:

```
private void SerialPortDataSource_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                var buffor = new byte[BytesToRead];
                Read(buffor, 0, buffor.Length);
                _receivedBytes = buffor;
                //wConsole.WriteLine(ArrayExtension.ToString(buffor));
                var dataLogger = DataLogger;
                if (dataLogger != null)
                {
                    dataLogger.WriteLine("- DR - {0}", true, BitConverterExtension.ToHexString(buffor));
                }

                if (OnDataReceived != null)
                {
                    OnDataReceived(this, buffor);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // sometimes DataReceived event is invoked after port is closed which causes InvalidOperationException
        }
    }
```

This method is working for me in many applications with variety serial port settings.